# Weka UI language configuration error while reading file

Tags: windows, dataset, weka

in attempts to implement Machine learning into my project, i used WEKA. And to train and test it, weka process collection of data which is in Russian Language. But in process of reading it shows unreadible ('Ð§Ñ, Ð¾ Ñ') characters. I understand that this is due to language configuration error, but i cant find a solution. Any help is apperciated

[WEKA UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pziR9.png)

i gave java 1.8, weka 3.8.
my dataset is like: "Российский ситком (ситуационная комедия) «Интерны», совмещенная адаптация «Клиники» и «Доктора Хауса»"
my folder is like:

-kino1tr:
   -good
   -bad
   -neutral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did stupid mistake. While loading data, there charSet field to specify language configuration. Thus, stating UTF-8 in charset resolves the issue